# Putting a closure into a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uikit, closures

In an iOS app I have a popup button that contains a list of item names that can change.
I am trying to make a dictionary of `[String : (String)->Void]` to store different actions to be performed based on the selected item.

The below function gives me the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to subscript of type '(String) -> Void'

Isn't my closure of type `(String)->Void`, or have I declared it incorrectly?

```
func selectOption(action : UIAction) {
    var actionDict : [String : (String)->Void] = [:]
    var assetNames : [String] = []
    assetNames = assets.map { asset in
        return asset.components(separatedBy: "@@@")[0]
    }
    var logAction = { (assetName: String) in
        print(assetName)
    }
    

    assetNames.forEach { an in
        actionDict[an] = logAction(an)
    }
}
```

I have a big gap in my understanding.
If I change my declaration of actionDict to be `()` then the code compiles but it just executes the closure when I run it and it hits the line `actionDict[an] = logAction(an)`, it just runs the closure rather than assigning it to the dictionary:

```
func selectOption(action : UIAction) {
    var actionDict : [String : ()] = [:]
    var assetNames : [String] = []
    assetNames = assets.map { asset in
        return asset.components(separatedBy: "@@@")[0]
    }
    var logAction : (String)->() = { (assetName: String)->() in
        print(assetName)
    }
    assetNames.forEach { an in
        actionDict[an] = logAction(an)
    }
    
    actionDict[action.title]
}
```

Comment: You are invoking the function rather than assigning its reference, so what actually would be inserted if this compiled would be an empty tuple (`Void`), because that's what `logAction` returns

Comment: Thank you. I thought I understood what you are telling me but I suspect I'm not getting it. (I've altered the code and edited my question, above.)

Comment: Quick search for `swift store closure as a dictionary object` comes up with several approaches...

Comment: Yes, I've visited several of them. Unfortunately I wasn't able to understand them such that I could apply them to what I am trying to do. I will keep at it. Thanks.

Comment: @psb - OK... your goal is a little confusing... what is `assets`? What do you expect to get with your `.map` and `asset.components(separatedBy: "@@@")[0]`?

Comment: Just got off of a flight (on which I had a minor revelation and now have a better grasp of dealing with closures). I have solve my issue and will update my post as soon as I can get to a computer.

Comment: @psb I rolled back your last edit. Instead of editing your question with the solution, you should post an actual answer below. That keeps the question and the answer separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
var assets: [String] = ["abc@@@XYZ", "mno@@@PQR@@@123", "xyz", "$#$#$"]

func selectOption(action : UIAction) {
    var actionDict : [String : ((String)->())] = [:]
    var assetNames : [String] = assets.map { $0.components(separatedBy: "@@@")[0] }

    var logAction : ((String)->()) = { assetName in
        print(assetName)
    }
    
    assetNames.forEach { an in
        // only logAction(an) will triggle/call stored closure 
               
        // Instead of that, you can create new closure with parameter
        actionDict[an] = { str in logAction(str) }
    }
}
```

---

now it depends on when calling `actionDict["abc"]("xyz")`.
what you expected?

---

1. If it should print `"abc"`, then:

> Initialization:
> `var actionDict : [String : (()->())] = [:]`
> setup:
> `actionDict[an] = { logAction(an) }`
> call:
> `actionDict["abc"]()`

---

2. If it should print `"xyz"`, then:

> A dictionary with the same type of closure (with a String parameter) in every value is meaningless.

---

3. It works if it varies by different functions.

> `actionDict["print"]("xyz")`, `actionDict["dump"]("abc")`
> `actionDict["typecast"]("mno")`, `actionDict["split"]("$#$#$")`

So this third one is what you're looking for!

Comment: Need some examples of input & output in the questions in order to comprehend the type of task being requested.